# tkinter top-level menues not showing with macOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, menu

Here is the classic code from [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm), which informed:

*Toplevel menus are displayed just under the title bar of the root or any other toplevel windows (or on Macintosh, along the upper edge of the screen). To create a toplevel menu, create a new Menu instance, and use add methods to add commands and other menu entries to it.*

But not working, No menues found. I expect there are `Welcome` and `Quit` to the right side of `python`. Any thing missed?

#### System info

- Python 3.7.5
- macOS Catalina
- TkVersion 8.6

```py
import tkinter as tk

def hello():
    print('Hi~')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("MacOS Catalina")
menubar  = tk.Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menubar)
menubar.add_command(label='Welcome', command=hello)
menubar.add_command(label='Quit', command=root.quit)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I know its an different topic, but how did you get MacOS darkmode to work with your Tkinter application? Because mine are always in light mode.

Comment: @Tom I have no idea. The dark mode appearance is running with **python 3.7.5** virtural envrironment created by [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), while in **python 3.7.3** virtual env by conda, is light. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OSX, you cannot put commands on the root menu. Apple simply doesn't allow it. You can only put other menus (cascades). For example:

```
...
menubar  = tk.Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menubar)

menu = tk.Menu(menubar)
menu.add_command(label="Welcome", command=hello)
menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="My Menu", menu=menu)
```

Comment: I know we can do this way. But I did not understand why cant my way? Would you further explain or some reference link?

Comment: @Kuo: you can't, because it's against Apple's human interface guidelines. They do not permit commands on the top menubar.